# Remove the community-wiki tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

The [community-wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/community-wiki) tag on SO does nothing except confuse some new users, who think that community wiki is simply a tag to put on their question.

I've already removed it from all CW questions except those that are locked. There are still around 20 non-CW questions with the tag; I'm posting here in lieu of going through them myself and flagging for moderator review.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention.  I cleaned up the last few and I'll add this to my ever-expanding list of tags that I periodically wish into the cornfield.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: your comment gave me an idea, posted here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32975/make-banned-tags-on-so-unselectable-by-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've removed the tags on all of the posts I can - the only ones left are the ones migrated to Meta

Comment: I left them on the non-wiki posts so that Bill or Marc could check whether they needed to be wikified.