# Make "banned" tags on SO unselectable by users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, moderators, moderator-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implement a Tag Black List](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list)

On the recent MSO post, [Remove the community-wiki tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32947/remove-the-community-wiki-tag), Bill the Lizard left the following comment:

> Thanks for bringing this to our attention. I cleaned up the last few and I'll add this to my ever-expanding list of tags that I periodically wish into the cornfield

Maybe you guys could make the tags on that list moderator-only tags, the same as `status-*` tags on MSO, so that users can't select them? Seems like it would save some moderator brain cycles, and the code is already there.

Comment: And add "plzsendtehcodez" to it.

Comment: @GMan, But what if I want teh codez sent to me?

Comment: Doing something intelligent with tags to help out the moderators? A great idea. And one stuck in limbo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14595/stop-stupid-tags, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2779/could-the-tagging-system-be-enhanced-to-support-tag-synonyms